# How come my app dies on AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net, web, appharbor

I have a web app that will run forever (at least for a few days) on my local machine using the technique (hack?) described in Jeff Atwood's post: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

However when I run it on App Harbor my app doesn't run for more than an hour or so (I'm not sure when it dies) as long as I hit the site it stays up so I'm assuming it is being killed after an idle period, but I'm not sure why.

My app doesn't save any state or persist anything. It makes web service calls and survives errors in any calls.

I turned on a ping service to keep my app alive but I'm curious why this works on my local machine but not on App Harbor?

Comment: Doesn't appHarbor kill the w3wp thread after it's been idle for x time?

Answer (score 4):

The guys behind App Harbor pays for EC2 instances for all running apps, so they naturally want to limit the cpu usage as much as possible. One way to achieve this is to shut down unused applications very fast and only restart them when someone actually try to access them. Paid hosting should not be limited in this way.

(As far as I have been informed they are able to host around 100k sites on less than twenty medium instances which is certainly quite impressive and calls for a very economic use of resources.)

To overcome the limitation you would need a cron job to ping your app harbour site. But this of course a quite recursive problem since you need app harbour to act as a cron job ;)

Answer (score 2):

AppHarbor recycles the Application Pool frequently to keep sleeping websites from using idle CPU time.  This is simply the price you pay of using a shared website hosting plan.

If you really want to run a background job then you should be using AppHarbor's background workers, since this is exactly the type of task they were built to run.

http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/background-workers

Simply build a new console application that runs your logic and include it in your solution.  When you push the code the workers will be started automatically.  If you happen to already have other exe's in your solution make sure to edit the app.config and set the 'deploy background worker' value to false.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at background workers but went with a website so the program can communicate progress / results to me and I can issue commands to it.